# Failure of code within dispatch_sync to execute

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

I have the following simple piece of code that fails to execute properly.  This item should be writing an array of objects to an sqlite database using an `FMDatabaseQueue` (_queue) that is instantiated as a static value at initialization time.  This is executing within a singleton.  Commenting out the dispatch_async wrapper results in proper execution, as demonstrated by the `NSLog()` statements. As you can see, I'd like execute this write operation in a background queue when called.  Other calls to `dispatch_async` work properly in the application (but not within the singleton) as do all FMDB operations NOT within a `dispatch_async` wrapper.

```
 -(void)addSafePersonEntryArray:(NSMutableArray *)per
 {
   NSLog(@"Reaches here with dispatch_async enabled");
    dispatch_async(
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{  //commenting out this
    NSLog(@"But not here");
    [_queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollBack) {
        NSLog(@"Nor here");
        [db setLogsErrors:YES];
        [db setTraceExecution:NO];
        [db setKey:self.secretKey];
        for(PersonObject *p in per){
            [self _addPersonEntryRecord:p db:db];
        }
    }];
});  //  and commenting out this as well as dispatch_async causes all NSLog() statements to be reached and the code works properly.
}
```

I instantiate the singleton like this:

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static AppManager *sharedAppManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedAppManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedAppManager;
}
```

I shall  be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Where's the singleton used? Do you use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` elsewhere and possible block it?

Comment: It's executed in the initial view controller, and I mention it as dispatch_async  works in other places.  The code in question is within the singleton - where I make all database calls.  I do use DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT elsewhere but I don't knowingly block it.

Comment: You mean that this code is part of `AppManager` and is called inside it's `init()` in the line `sharedAppManager = [[self alloc] init];`? Is that where you create view controllers? What happens when you use another queue?

Comment: Yes, and I instantiate it the first time in viewDidLoad of the entry view controller.  I don't create anything within the singleton; I use the singleton as a resource to group all FMDatabase calls together through the FMDatabaseQueue (_queue) that I instantiate in the singleton.